# SignalR connection management in a web farm

Tags: signalr, web-farm

We are using SignalR in a large scale web application. We have deployed multiple web servers handling signalR connections. We have our own Redis backplane implemented, I have the following question:
SignalR makes three calls to the server: 1) negotiate, 2) connect and 3) start. If we have a web farm behind a Load Balancer and these three calls end up going to three different servers, would the state of connections be corrupted on all three servers? What would happen in this scenario? I am not talking about message delivery.

More specifically:

1. Would a second webserver be able to understand the connectionId
   produced by the negotiate call?
2. What happens when the physical connection(websockets) is established
   on a different server and then the start call goes to another
   server?

I know for a fact that SignalR does not communicate the connection info between the servers. I am wondering about the state of connections in memory on these three servers.
I read the another question related to this, but it talks only about message delivery. For us, message delivery is not a problem. I want to understand the final state of the connections if these three calls end up going to different servers.

The question that I already went through to get an answer:
[SignalR connection affinity in web-farm scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894577/signalr-connection-affinity-in-web-farm-scenario)

Since our load balancer maintains stickiness, I am unable to confirm what will happen when the stickiness goes away. I want to be prepared for that eventuality.

Comment: Hey guruprasath, just wondering if you ever got an answer to this question?  Currently, we have a farm that serves the application and we're using a Redis backplane hosted in Azure. In my case, the load balancer does not have sticky sessions on and I'm seeing timeouts and disconnects with websockets, which I believe is the what you feared.  The confusing part to me is based on what I read in the documentation, the transport connection is directly with the backplane, which would mean the load balancer makes no difference... but we don't see issues with a single node environment.

Comment: @ammills01, I did not get an answer. I tried posting in one other jabber channel, but no luck. Based on what you have described, I am guessing that your issue is not related to stickiness. We use our own Redis cluster with a custom implementation of backplane. So, I am unable to talk about the stability of the Redis backplane provided by them. My understanding is that the transport connection is not with the backplane(which would be a security issue). The transport connection is with the front-end webservers supporting the websockets. So, stickiness of the load balancer could matter a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After a bit more digging I came to the same conclusion you mentioned here, transport is with the SignalR server so without sticky sessions on the requests were bouncing all over and failing. When that happens, you get timeouts and if you configured longPolling, or other transport technologies, when you established your SignalR connection it will fail over to one of those. For us, it hits longPolling and the app seems to work fine from there on out, just takes more resources on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I'm taking the time to answer because I have a similar setup, albeit with different technologies. It might not completely solve your problems, but I think a lot of similarity can be drawn.

Our scenario real-time communication (i.e. chat messages). The server will notify the client at anytime when another user logs in, disconnects, etc.

Tech stack below:

Client: AngularJS App

CDN: serving static resources (HTML, CSS, images)

Load balancer: setup in Azure

Multiple WebApps: running ASP.NET Core

Multiple SQL Server databases: mirrored

The key point here is the application remains stateless throughout. At any point, a client may disconnect/reconnect and retrieve the same set of information it had before disconnecting.

- Users are authenticated using a token mechanism (OAuth in our case). All user info (user id, etc.) are encrypted int he token.
- Connection is established, and routed to any one of the web apps running.
- Webapp stores connection info in a database table.
- Webapp retrieves all "friends" of users who has a connection in the database.
- Webapp sends list back to client.
- Whenever a user disconnects, webapp receives disconnect event and removes record form database.
- Whevenver a user reconnects, webapp adds the connection back, and sends the user the current list of online connections/clients.

It is up to the client to maintain which state it is in and how to react to updates in client lists.

This approach is similar to the one mentioned in the answer you posted in your question.

I believe the essential concept here is the backplane. It persists the state, instead of just communicating it around the servers.

A related blog post here may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

(Take a look at the "More than one server" scenario)

Comment: Reading a little more on the backplane answer, I believe the concept is the same. I've given an outline of my approach. There are optimisations that we have done, obviously, such as responding with a list of newly connected clients after each request, instead of the whole list (the cursor things mentioned in your post).